# Twython Twitter Post is Truncated

Tags: python, twitter, twython, twitterapi-python

I'm trying to get some tweets using Twython, but even with tweet_mode:extended the results are still truncated. Any ideas how I can get the full text.

```
def requestTweets(topic, resultType = "new", amount = 10, language = "en"):
'''Get the n tweets for a topic, either newest (new) or most popular (popular)'''
#Create Query
query = {'q': topic,
        'result_type': resultType,
        'count': amount,
        'lang': language,
        'tweet_mode': 'extended',
        }

#Get Data
dict_ = {'user': [], 'date': [], 'full_text': [],'favorite_count': []}
for status in python_tweets.search(**query)['statuses']:
    dict_['user'].append(status['user']['screen_name'])
    dict_['date'].append(status['created_at'])
    dict_['full_text'].append(status['full_text'])
    dict_['favorite_count'].append(status['favorite_count'])

# Structure data in a pandas DataFrame for easier manipulation
df = pd.DataFrame(dict_)
df.sort_values(by='favorite_count', inplace=True, ascending=False)
return df

tweets = requestTweets("chocolate")
for index, tweet in tweets.iterrows():
    print("***********************************")
    print(tweet['full_text'])
```

Results look like this:

[image]

Comment: Can you check the "truncated" parameter in Twython? If it is true, I suggest you use a different package. I had some issues with Twython and the limits on the Twitter API (which is why I used the package I suggested below).

Answer (score 2):

I know it's kind of late! but I put the answer to whom may need it.

I'm using twython==3.9.1 and its possible to get the full text of tweets with the below snippet code:

```
twython: Twython
tweets = twython.get_user_timeline(
        screen_name=user_screen_name, # or user id
        count=200, #  max count is 200
        include_retweets=include_retweets, # could be False or True
        exclude_replies=exclude_replies, # could be False or True
        tweet_mode='extended', # to get tweets full text
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a way to do it with Twython, so I switched to tweepy in the end, still, if anyone has an answer, that would be great.